# $\mathbb{C}P^2$ as a $U(1)$ bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-space, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Can $\mathbb{C}P^2$ be the total space of a principal $U(1)$-bundle?

Since the universal bundle of $U(1)$ is $S^\infty \to \mathbb{C}P^\infty$, then we would just need to find a 3-manifold $M$ and a continuous map $f : M \to \mathbb{C}P^\infty$ such that the pullback bundle $f^* S^\infty = \mathbb{C}P^2$, or prove that such thing can't occur, but I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $\mathbb{CP}^2$ were the total space of principal $U(1)$-bundle over some space $B$, so that there is a fiber bundle $U(1) \to \mathbb{CP}^2 \to B$.

Note that the map $\mathbb{CP}^2 \to B$ is surjective, so $B$ is compact. If $B$ is a manifold (or even just a CW complex), it follows that the homology groups of $B$ are finitely generated, and all but finitely many of them vanish. Therefore $B$ has a well-defined Euler characteristic.

As the Euler characteristic is multiplicative for fiber bundles, we see that $\chi(\mathbb{CP}^2) = \chi(U(1))\chi(B)$, but this is impossible as $\chi(U(1)) = 0$ and $\chi(\mathbb{CP}^2) = 3 \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks! Beautiful.
And since the Euler characteristic of any odd-dimensional compact closed manifold is 0 **, then CP^2 could never be the total space of any fiber bundle over a manifold. 

** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Arbitrary_dimensions

Comment: Well, there's $\ast \to \mathbb{CP}^2 \to \mathbb{CP}^2$ and $\mathbb{CP}^2\to\mathbb{CP}^2\to\ast$. However, $\mathbb{CP}^2$ does not arise as the total space of a fiber bundle with manifold fiber and base, both of positive dimension. Again, this follows from multiplicativity of the Euler characteristic. Note that your comment is insufficient for the case where the base and fiber have dimension two.